# run python script in windows scheduled task

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, automation

I use this [repo](https://gist.github.com/valferon/4d6ebfa8a7f3d4e84085183609d10f14) to backup my postgers db.

I run it manually by this command :

```
python postgres_manager.py  --configfile psql.config --action backup --verbose VERBOSE
```

how can i run this script by windows scheduled task

Comment: When creating a new action you should be able to add arguments, so you could select python as the programm that should be run and then add the python script with all it's args to the argument section. Also don't forget to set the working directory (`starts in (optional):`). [Also have a look at this tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10#section-how-to-create-an-advanced-task-on-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by tomdevin, using Windows task scheduler works nicely. However, I generally use batch files (.bat) to schedule. In the batch file I write the call to python.

For example, here I activate the python virtual environment, move to the project folder and then call the python script main.py with 2 command line options. After running the script it calls an 'EXIT' statement to exit the terminal again.

```
call C:\venv\Scripts\activate.bat && cd C:\GIT\ProjectFolder && C:\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\ProjectFolder\main.py --dataloc "C:/Data/" --saveloc "C:/Output/"
EXIT
```

You can simply copy paste this in a Notepad and save it as 'run.bat' or whatever you like. Then, from task scheduler under actions, you call 'start a program' and point to your .bat file.

This method provides some more flexibility and allows easy use of virtual environments.